# How to migrate a programme or game onto a new computer if installation disk is cracked

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation, windows-vista, windows-registry

To begin with; I appreciate there will likely be a different answer for each piece of software, so I'll go specific:

I would like to transfer Rome Total War onto a new computer. Unfortunately since the game was first installed, Disk 1 has become cracked so the game can't be reinstalled that way. Is there any other way of migrating games without the installation disks?

My first (uneducated) guess would be to copy over all game files *and* associated registry keys (not sure which ones though)

Another potential avenue: We have been running the game up until now with a no-CD software crack (i.e. some 3rd party software which allows the game to run without the CD being in the drive). I wonder if there is an equivalent for installing a new game?

Any insights would be much appreciated as internet searches have drawn blanks.

*NB the old computer is on vista, the new one will be windows 10*

Comment: Most applications don't actually require them being installed.  Have you tried just transferring the directory to the new computer?

Comment: You may want to check if the game has any registry settings as well. If you find anything related to the game in the registry you could just recreate those on the new computer

Comment: @EricF I don't really know my way around the registry, what should I typically look for/ can I search it?

Comment: @Greedo  Hard to say specifically for your particular game.. but usually if you press windows key + r, type regedit, click ok, goto Computer>HKEY_Local_Machine>Software and then look for your game / software's name, most items will be under here usually

Comment: You're already using an illegal crack... What exactly is preventing you from downloading the installer from somewhere and install it as usual?

Comment: @MichaelBay - NoCD cracks are sort of a gray area if you actually own the game.

Comment: @Ramhound Agreed, but the same goes for the entire software and that was my main point: Why going to such lengths including registry keys when the game can be easily installed the normal way by obtaining the installer from... Somewhere?

Comment: @Ramhound No doubt the solution (Steam) found by the OP is the best one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround:

Turns out if you have the product key still (which I did), you can install some games from Steam

<kbd>Library</kbd> -> <kbd>Add a Game</kbd> -> <kbd>Activate a Product on Steam</kbd>

If you don't have a physical copy of the product key, you might still be able to find it by running [Belarc Advisor](https://www.belarc.com/products_belarc_advisor) on the computer with the game installed

Comment: Nice :) By googling I've found out the game is available at Steam and I know some games bough outside Steam can be used with the same serial / product key -and- I was about to suggest that in comments as an alternative but refrained from doing that at the last moment because I wasn't sure about this one. This is the best solution because the game installed by Stean is guaranteed to work in Windows 10 whereas your old version from the CDs may not. Already upvoted but you should also accept your own answer.